# Check apache server-status without URL

Tags: apache-2.2

I just found that http://www.apache.org/server-status display current process, URL and vhost for good. However, `#SetHandler server-status` is commented out on our server and disabled the URL. But they still load the mod_status.

Is there any alt. method that I could access runtime information for diagnostics (find slow URL or too many requests), *without* retouching the httpd.conf? All I have is SSH connection with right to sudo.

It is Apache HTTPD 2.2 on linux, if it matters.

Comment: You have to touch the httpd.conf to fix it! Why do you not want to fix it?

Comment: which distribution of linux?

Comment: Why does it matter if you need to touch that file - if you "have SSH connection with right to sudo"

Comment: @portforwardpodcast It is an unfortunate oldish Centos 5.

Comment: @ETL It does matter. I am not in a role responsible of server maintenance. I should not do any permanent changes, due to political reasons.

Answer (score 3):

You can run `apachectl status` or `apachectl fullstatus`, which give the mod_status output.

Comment: If you have ever read their code. apachectl is doing fetching http://localhost/server-status and reformat

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://fabletech.com/ftss to connect to the unix domain socket of an Apache scoreboard to get the information from mod_status. It would require editing the httpd.conf and restarting though.

If you're not able to add this then the information would have to be gathered from a large number of sources. For instance netstat, lsof of apache processes, strace of apache processes and the like. These would not be presented in a friendly manner like the mod_status display is.

Comment: The link is dead :-(

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20130703084607/http://fabletech.com/ftss